# Use PowerShell to view contents of the Global Assembly Cache (GAC)

Tags: powershell, gac

Is there a way to use PowerShell to view the contents of the GAC?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another option is that the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) installs a GAC provider, so you can do this:

```
dir gac:
```

If you are on PowerShell V2, be sure to grab the 1.2 Beta.

Comment: kewl.  I did  not know about that.

Answer (score 7):

As stated in [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the default location for the global assembly cache is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly. In earlier versions of the .NET Framework, the default location is %windir%\assembly.

You may want to search in the appropriate subdir or even in both of them.

Answer (score 6):

To list entries in the GAC;

```
gacutil -l
```

In powershell you could parse the text output of the above.
I don't know of a managed interface to inspect the GAC.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question. The question became more prominent with .Net 4.0 and there not being a Windows Explorer shell plugin available to view the contents. GacUtil works, but is not flexible enough and takes a lot to install. The PowerShell Community Extensions option is to limited in it's functionality and contains to many other CmdLets that I don't need. Therefore I've written my own PowerShell module to view and change the GAC. It can be found on http://powershellgac.codeplex.com

This project has moved to GitHub.  You can now find it on:

https://github.com/LTruijens/powershell-gac

It can also be found in the PowerShell Gallery:

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Gac/1.0.1

```
# Show the assemblies in the GAC, including the file version
Get-GacAssembly SomeCompany* | Format-Table -View FileVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

I successfully listed GAC using this code snippet:

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry' -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCR:\Installer\Assemblies\Global' | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty
```

Solution taken from [here](https://dscottraynsford.wordpress.com/2018/09/10/list-global-assembly-cache-using-powershell/comment-page-1/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it just from a command prompt:

```
cd C:\Windows\assembly
dir
```

The GAC has a specific directory structure, and you should not go moving or deleting things in there using the command prompt - rather use windows explorer (gui) or gacutil (cli)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for a specific assembly in the GAC.

Also note, since MS has changed the GAC structure you can use the -Recurse option from the root to search all the GAC.

```
CD C:\Windows\assembly 
ls -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -like "*log4net*"}
```