# How to check GAC assembly details on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: gac, windows-server-2012

How can you check GAC assembly details Windows Server 2012? I managed to register a DLL via Powershell, now I need to verify that it is really done.

Comment: Have you tried [gacutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx)?

Comment: @Alberto: gacutil is a development tool, it's probably not installed on the server.

Comment: I see... so maybe you can try with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882854/use-powershell-to-view-contents-of-the-global-assembly-cache-gac

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You are probably looking for the custom look of the GAC directory that you were familiar with in .NET versions prior to 4.0.  Which stored the GAC in the c:\windows\assembly window and used a custom shell extension to flatten the directory structure into a list of assemblies.

The shell extension is no longer used for .NET versions 4.0 and up.  You have .NET 4.5 on that machine, its GAC is stored in c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly.  You just get to see the actual directory structure.  Locating the assembly isn't that difficult, start in the GAC_MSIL directory and you should have no trouble locating your assembly there by its name.  Locate the folder with the same *display name* as your assembly.  It will have a subdirectory that has an unspeakable name that's based on the version and public key token, that subdirectory contains the DLL.

If your assembly is a mixed-mode assembly created with C++/CLI then you'd start from either the GAC_32 or GAC_64 directory.

Comment: thanks, this seems to be the case. I found the details looking for.

Answer (score 11):

just try with this path

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly

Comment: it displays only folders, special folder assembly's shell extension seems not available in windows server 2012.

Comment: @BinuBhasuran I think the shell extension was dropped with .NET 4.0 (Windows Server 2012 comes with .NET 4.5).

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to use PowerShell. I've created a PowerShell module which allows you to see and manipulate the GAC contents. You can find it [here](http://powershellgac.codeplex.com).

```
# Show the assemblies in the GAC, including the file version
Get-GacAssembly SomeCompany* | Format-Table -View FileVersion
```

Answer (score 1):

The gacutil.exe has a parameter to do this. If you run

```
gacutil.exe /l
```

You will get a list of registrations.